# string does not exist in current context

Tags: c#

string declared inside class MyClass(TransactionId And pnrno)
is not working in button click

> ERROR MESSAGE
>
> the name (TransactionId And pnrno) does not exsist in current context

```
class MyClass
{   
        
    public string TransactionID { get; set; }
    public string pnrno { get; set; }
    public string trainno { get; set; }
    public string dateofbooking { get; set; }
    public string className { get; set; }
    public string Quota { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}

protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=logistics.jayom.org,1434;Initial Catalog=logistics_kl;User ID=kl_admin;Password=Admin@2222");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into testfbhv (TransactionId, pnrno) values('" + TransactionID + "','" + pnrno + "')", con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: What value do you expect them to currently have?

Comment: its depends what user will enter

Comment: You should create an instance of your class first `MyClass cs = new MyClass();`
Then:
    `cs.TransactionID`

Comment: ok, think where the user will enter them, where you store them, and how you expect your method to get it.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18233630/1324033)

Comment: @Sayse user will enter in a textbox but if this problem will be solved i will do all the following steps easily

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`btnsave_Click` will be part of say `Form1` class, not part of your `MyClass` you've shown. As a result, no it cant see the string you mentioned.

You would need to have created an instance of `MyClass`, and set some values to it.. (not mentioned in your example code) so then you might be able to..

Lets assume that `Form1` has a variable of `MyClass` called `mc` - and is made on creation or such: then you your button click you can have `mc.TransactionalID`

Comment: Think of it as human terms. Let's say you're the form with the button click on it.. You know what you're thinking about all the things you have.. Im "MyClass" you cant tell what Im thinking without asking me. Classes are like people they are independent and you cant see something that a) you dont have permission to b) you cant call "transactionid" cos you dont have one, but I do.. You need to ask me for mine..   But also, you need me to exist before you can ask me, non static classes are just templates, so you need to have made an instance of me (cookie cutter) so you can talk to me.

Comment: I am very new in  c# how to make an instance of a class

Comment: @Ibibo I mentioned in my comment below your question. You should create an instance of your class first like this `MyClass cs = new MyClass();` Then you can use it in your `insert` command like this: `cs.TransactionID`.

Comment: i used instance but forgetted thank you guys for your support