# Record the picturebox area

Tags: c#, screen, picturebox, recording

I am able to get the width and length of the *picturebox1*, but i cant find the correct code to get the x and y position of the *picturebox1*, i have already tried following code;

```
job = new ScreenCaptureJob();
System.Drawing.Size area = SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Size;
Rectangle captureRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width -(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width % 4), pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height - (pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height % 4));
```

I used *screencapturejob* from MEE to do the recording process.

Comment: i use this code from the link but theres message : the name picturebox1 doesnt exist in the current context, do you have any ide how to fix this ?

Comment: I don't know how exactly you use `picturebox1` and where it is defined, because you didn't show us that. But in any case this error is quite generic and boils down to an attempt to use variable/field in a scope that is unaware of that variable/field - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233630/variable-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
Point pt = pictureBox1.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
Rectangle captureRect = new Rectangle(pt.X, pt.Y, pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width - (pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width % 4), pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height - (pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height % 4));
```

Comment: i use that code but theres message : the name picturebox1 doesnt exist in the current context, what should i do then ?

Comment: This code would have to be executed within the Form containing pictureBox1.  If this is not the case, then you'd need to **pass** a reference to that PictureBox from the Form to where ever you're attempting to access it.   We'd need to see more of your code to better help you.

Comment: Stupid question...did the original code you posted generate that error?  Anywhere it worked, the new code should also work.

Comment: hey it solved, i try to rewrite the code.. im sorry but im new to this C# programming,, i will try to get better then